# FEMA NFHL Flood Hazard Zones ArcGIS Online API access through VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba, api, arcgis

I am trying to access ArcGIS Online with an API through VBA. My end goal is to provide a List of Lat/Longs in Excel, then have the FEMA Flood Hazard Zone layer return what flood zone my Lat/Long is in (e.g. "X", "AE", etc.).

I have only found a couple resources but cannot interpret how to access the data from the layer. ANY help is really appreciated. I'm not a pro at this by any means, but I'm competent.

Here are some resources I've found:

https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28

https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/wps/portal/NFHLWMS

https://msc.fema.gov/portal/home

Some code I have (clearly not complete):

```vb
Function FEMA(LatLong As String)

Dim surl As String Dim oXH As Object Dim bodytxt As String

surl = "https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28" & LatLong

Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")

With oXH
    .Open "get", surl, False
    .send
    bodytxt = .responseText
End With

Cells(3, 3).Value = bodytxt


Set oXH = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Dump the text and describe what you're trying to pull out of it

Comment: You probably don't want to parse the `responseText` manually. Use the MSXML library to query the DOM instead - your question is *too broad* to be answered on this site though; you'll want to research about using the MSXML library, and if you hit a wall with a *specific* problem, then asking here can help you.. but as it stands it's unfortunately unclear whether you're asking for links to tutorials (off-topic), or for people to do the work for you (off-topic as well).

Comment: Ok thanks for the input, I'll try to be more clear. I do not work with trying to access data from the internet much, but I know that under the right circumstances, I can do it through VBA. I found a link: https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28 ...which appear to take me to where I can request data from ArcGIS online. This link is a LAYER for a map I need to access. I would like to provide a LAT and LONG to this LAYER and have it return a FIELD (Field name: "FLD_ZONE") of wherever my lat/long is on that map.

Comment: Give us a URL of a file you're trying to pull, or you're not going to get any help here and the question will be closed.

Comment: I would like to start by saying that just because you do not understand my question does not mean that I have asked a bad question. I have even tried to clarify my question in great detail. Nonetheless, I have resolved my issue... I was trying to access a LAYER from ArcGIS. This contains polygons that are identified as Flood Hazard Zones. The link to this layer was stated in my original question... I was trying to pass a Lat/Long to this layer to have it return whatever the Zone name was by determining which polygon it is in. Turns out this cannot be returned in an XML format, only JSON...

Comment: ... Here is the query string for anybody who needs it in the future... This is for a Lat: 32.333, Long: -96.6666 and returns the FLOOD HAZARD ZONE that this point is in. It is returned in a JSON format...

Comment: https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28...

Comment: .../query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-96.6666%2C32.333&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelWithin&relationParam=&outFields=FLD_ZONE&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=pjson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue... As I stated, I was trying to access a LAYER from ArcGIS. This contains polygons that are identified as Flood Hazard Zones. The link to this layer was stated in my original question... I was trying to pass a Lat/Long to this layer to have it return whatever the Zone name was by determining which polygon it is in. Turns out this cannot be returned in an XML format, only JSON. Here is the query string for anybody who needs it in the future... This is for a Lat: 32.333, Long: -96.6666 and returns the FLOOD HAZARD ZONE that this point is in. It is returned in a JSON format...

[hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-96.6666%2C32.333&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelWithin&relationParam=&outFields=FLD_ZONE&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=pjson](http://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-96.6666%2C32.333&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelWithin&relationParam=&outFields=FLD_ZONE&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=pjson)

... [This Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/6db2y0/using_python_to_extracting_flood_hazard_info_from/) helped me greatly.